# What does "Perform GC" button do in jconsole?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jmx

There is a button "Perform GC" in jconsole, anyone knows what exactly happens if I click that button, it's invoking `System.gc()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find out by yourself. The code of JConsole is part of OpenJDK.
You can also check it out on [grepcode.com](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/sun/tools/jconsole/MemoryTab.java#MemoryTab.gc%28%29).

The button calls a `gc()` method of an object implementing `MemoryMXBean` which is most probably implemented by [`com.sun.management.MemoryImpl`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/sun/management/MemoryImpl.java?av=h#MemoryImpl) class. This class contains an implementation of `gc()` method which looks like this:

```
public void gc() {
    Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
}
```

Now, if you consider the implementation of `gc()` method in [`java.lang.System`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/System.java#System.gc%28%29) which looks like this:

```
public void gc() {
    Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
}
```

the answer to your question is: *Technically no, but it does the same thing.*

Answer (score 2):

According to [this link](http://tomcat.10.n6.nabble.com/OT-Jconsole-Perform-GC-td2007229.html), yes, it does perform `System.gc()`.

Comment: "Technically" wrong, but as you stated, they both end up at "Runtime.getRuntime().gc();".

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much. The GC Button in the [MemoryTab](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/tools/jconsole/MemoryTab.java#MemoryTab.gc%28%29) in JConsole calls [MemoryTab.gc()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/tools/jconsole/MemoryTab.java#MemoryTab.gc%28%29) which in turn calls the target JVM's [MemoryMXBean.gc()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/management/MemoryMXBean.java#MemoryMXBean.gc%28%29). The javadoc says this call is equivalent to [java.lang.System.gc()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/System.java#System.gc%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

I fear they do pretty much the same under the hood, but I'm not sure I agree with the description that says:

> The Memory tab features a “Perform GC” button that you can click to perform garbage collection whenever you want.

When actually `System.gc()` is just a suggestion for the VM:

> Calling the gc method suggests that the Java Virtual Machine expend effort toward recycling unused objects in order to make the memory they currently occupy available for quick reuse. When control returns from the method call, the Java Virtual Machine has made a best effort to reclaim space from all discarded objects.

Should they do the same, I would not dare to say you can do it *whenever you want*.